# How do I return the day of an inputed date?

Tags: python, datetime, input

I tried to use this format, with 'datetime' [My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5KnH.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the question instead of linking to a picture of it.  Other people can't run your picture in their environment to help you debug it.  Unless the issue is super obvious at a glance (it's not to me btw) people generally need to be able to run code to tell you why it's not working.

Comment: don't post code as an image. post it as text within the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `f''` format string :

```
print(f'{ delta.days } days have past since date 1 to date 2.')
```

Comment: Thank you!! Thank you very much!